Running PowerShell With Admin as a Non-Admin user
I am trying to run PowerShell as an admin, while I am on a school laptop. The application I am trying to run only works on usb drives for some reason, and because of this, I want to create a virtual disk that will allow me make the computer think it’s in a drive instead. Not sure if it’ll work though, as I have little experience in languages like PowerShell and all that.
The computer has no access to cmd, or literally anything else that may be able to give me some kind of admin (Task Manager, gpedit, etc.).
I’ve searched the internet but I can’t find a way to avoid the UAC.
I have seen that there are some apps that may be able to bypass the UAC, not sure what they are though.
I just need to bypass the UAC for PowerShell while keeping my account as a non-administrative one, or another way to run the previously mentioned application.
As I don’t know much about the .bat and .ps1 languages besides some of the basic commands, I’m not sure what more I could of tried besides using Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser in PowerShell or set __COMPAT_LAYER=RunAsInvoker in a .bat file.
I’ve also tried using something like one drive or a network drive.

My apologies if the question seems weirdly worded; just ask for clarification. This is the first time I do anything with the UAC so I’m not sure if what I’m doing will make sense, nor if it will work. But even if it seems stupid, there is no harm in trying ideas out.

You're asking for methods to bypass built in security checks. This doesn't seem like the right forum for that kind of question. Maybe SuperUser would be a better site for this?

Well true that, but I am also asking to do so with powershell. I will ask in SuperUser if my question can’t be answered via powershell code

At a fundamental level: you cannot. Windows is a secure operating system. If you are a standard user you cannot simply become an administrator. Imagine if you could do what you're asking: "IT granted me standard user access,but I want to bypass security and become an administrator."  If you could just become an administrator  that would be a horrible security hole.

I am very much aware, but as said in another comment of mine, there is no harm in asking, just in case it is possible. It seems this is not possible. thanks for the help anyway!

$currentPid = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
$principal = new-object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal($currentPid)
$adminRole=[System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator

if ($principal.IsInRole($adminRole))
{
   $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = $myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition + "(Admin)"
   clear-host
}
else
{
   $newProcess = new-object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo "PowerShell";
   $newProcess.Arguments = $myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition;
   $newProcess.Verb = "runas";
   [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($newProcess);
   break
}


That is a good way to self elevate, but the OP specifically asked for a way to bypass UAC, and that will definitely trigger UAC when it starts the elevated process.

As @TheMadTechnician said, it does seem like a good way to elevate myself, but as TheMadTechnician also said, it brings up a UAC prompt once ran.
